# hibernate plugin library not getting added

Tags: hibernate, grails

I downgraded my hibernate version to "hibernate:3.6.10.18" from "hibernate4:4.3.6.1" (runtime). Now I get this error, when I run my grails application:

```
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
........................................
..2016-08-23 11:21:36,986 [main] WARN  grails.plugin.webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin  - Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig
2016-08-23 11:21:37,408 [main] WARN  grails.plugin.webxml.WebxmlGrailsPlugin  - Did not find application config file: WebXmlConfig
|Running Grails application
2016-08-23 11:21:45,347 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/utilityapplication]  - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2016-08-23 11:21:57,113 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    ... 4 more
2016-08-23 11:21:57,113 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    ... 4 more
2016-08-23 11:21:57,129 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/utilityapplication]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    ... 4 more
2016-08-23 11:21:57,332 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart
2016-08-23 11:21:57,348 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext  - Context [/utilityapplication] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-08-23 11:21:57,364 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol  - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/utilityapplication
```

Comment: May you please add the Config.groovy here.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate cache couldn't be created, because the class `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory` could not be found. 
So, you have to change the cache factory inside your Config.groovy (or application.yml if you are using Grails 3+). 
To do so, you have to set the field from:

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
```

to:

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
```

However, you should have a look to this [page](http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/performanceTuning.html#s2). It will explain you why you **must** use hibernate 4.X EhCache instead of hibernate 3.X EhCache.